# Calculate how many cookies are set in PHP

Tags: php

How do I check how many cookies has been set without actually checking name by name such as **$_COOKIE['im_a_cookie'];** I have a function that in order to loop properly I need to validate how many cookies are set. how would I check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count($_COOKIE)` should return the length of any array

Comment: Thanks so that will return the length of all cookies regardless of their names?

Comment: yes. it will return the count of all defined items in an array. in your case the global array $_COOKIE

Comment: Thanks, I created a for loop just to do this to count every cookies, but it was hard to keep up as all cookies name would have to be ("name" + int) so i could specify each one of them in the for loop. this is much easier and readable now.